# MATCH AGAINST . Не ищет полноценно

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. В колонке  `name_adv` есть запись "Продам б.у автомобиль"
Делаю запрос по слову `б.у`

```
  select * from bazardnua_advert advert where
  MATCH (advert.name_adv) AGAINST ('+б.у' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Ничего не ищет. Если убрать точку или использовать другие входящие слова - ищет . 
В конфиге Mysql  стоит поиск минимум на 2 символа

Подскажите, почему, собственно, не идет поиск?

Я так понимаю, что дело в самой точке ?

Попробовал как-то так и без результата

```
AGAINST ('+\"б.у\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Индексы прописаны

Comment: `AGAINST ('"б.у"')` что возвращает?

Comment: @Visman я этой ночью пытался чего-то вменяемого добиться в [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40e72/5), но так ничего и не получилось. Я, конечно, к своему стыду, про существование `MATCH AGAINST` узнал только из этого вопроса, но всё же.

Comment: я просто не сильно силен в английском, но данный вопрос уже поднимался на других ресурсах. Но так и не понял, что нужно сделать , чтобы работало . Знаю, что при обычном LIKE нужно использовать РЕГАПСы

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087884/full-stop-period-operator-in-match-against 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404932/mysql-match-fulltext

Comment: Работать с точкой, запятой и пробелом не будет вероятно из-за `The built-in FULLTEXT parser determines where words start and end by looking for certain delimiter characters; for example,   (space), , (comma), and . (period).` Получается, что `б.у` для парсера это два слова, каждое из которых длиной в 1 букву.